# In CSS how do I style checkbox or radio button for pressed state apart from checked and not checked?

Tags: css, checkbox, radio-button, togglebutton

I am using invisible radio buttons and checkboxes with visible labels to create mode UI (single mode active at any time) and toggle buttons respectively. Ideally I want to have a different image for each of the following states

1. Unchecked
2. Pressed
3. Checked

I have used the following template. The :checked and :not(:checked) selectors are working. For buttons elements, :active seems to work for mouse down/pressed state. For checkboxes and radiobuttons, they don't seem to work. How do I do a style for just mouse down/pressed state?

```
    input#toggle_button:not(:checked) ~label{
      content: url(../assets/button_toggle_normal.png);
    }

    input#toggle_button:checked ~label{
      content: url(../assets/button_toggle_selected.png);
    }

    input#toggle_button:active ~label{
      content: url(../assets/button_toggle_pressed.png);
    }
```

Comment: If you're wanting an in-between state, you might want to use `:focus` and have four variants- normal, focus-normal, selected, focus-selected. `:active` doesn't work on checkboxes, but `:focus` works on all `input`. The effect won't be for "while-pressing", but it will be a good usability boon (which can be paired with `:hover` for mousers) and provides similar feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there would be a pure CSS solution to this, I would go and use Javascript / jQuery for this:

```
$("input#toggle_button ~label").on("mousedown", function(){
  $(this).addClass("pressed");
}).on("mouseup", function(){
  $(this).removeClass("pressed");
});
```

Check this Codepen: http://codepen.io/kaoz70/pen/JKWXvx

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `:active` in conjunction with checkboxes and radio buttons.

Per [the W3 standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#selector-active), `:active` only works on button inputs:

> If the element is an `input` element whose `type` attribute is in the Submit Button, Image Button, Reset Button, or Button state

You may need to come up with some clever workaround, such as:

```
$('[type="checkbox"]').bind('mousedown', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}).bind('mouseup mouseout change', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

*Note: the active state should probably take into account spacebar keydown events and touch events, as well.*

Comment: tbh it might be better to make a split select-press and deselect-press image, and then attach it to `:focus` instead. Avoids the need for JS/JQ mucking, while giving a similar (arguably better for usability) effect. Oh, and kudos for linking the standard. Slightly wrong in your paraphrase, though, it's at also valid for `a` tags, as well as a few others (listed in the standard)